# Is there any degree 6 irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$ whose Galois group is $A_4$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I know that $A_4$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_6$, so transitivity is not critical in this problem.

I tried to find irreducible polynomials of form $X^6-a(a \in \mathbb{Q})$, but their Galois groups seems to be $D_6$ when the order is $12$.

Please let me know if there is a simple example. I think there is no degree $6$ irreducible polnomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ whose Galois group is $A_4$.

Comment: What do you mean with the Galois group of a polynomial?

Comment: @joseabp91 The Galois group of its splitting field over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: There certainly exists a degree six irreducible rational polynomial whose Galois Group is $A_4$. I will see if I can dig out the details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are $A_4$-Galois extensions of $\Bbb Q$. Let $L$ be one of them. The group
$A_4$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $2$. Let $K=L^H$ be its fixed field. The subgroup $H$ is not normal in $A_4$; therefore the Galois closure of $K$ is $L$. As we are 
in characteristic zero, then $K=\Bbb Q(a)$ for some $a$. The minimal polynomial
of $a$ over $\Bbb Q$ has degree six, and its Galois group is $A_4$.

Comment: Thanks. I found an irreducible polynomial $-64 - 48 x^2 + x^6$ whose Galois group is $A_4$. It highly depends on the given algorithm and the fact that the Galois group of $x^4 + 8 x + 12$ is $A_4$.

Comment: @ChoMedit: Here's another one:$\;\,x^6-3x^2-1$.

Comment: @ChoMedit: This all suggests let $q(y)$ be an irreducible cubic with Galois Group $S_3$ and let $x^2=y$ so that $p(x^2)=q(y)$. Then there is another automorphism of roots which takes each root to its negative. That looks like $A_4$ to me. There has to be an element of $G$ of order $2$ which is the product of three transpositions.

Comment: Another possible construction would be to take $q(y)$ as an irreducible cubic over $\mathbb Q(i)$ and having three complex roots (discriminant not a square). Then $q\bar q$ will be a candidate sextic over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks for your insightful comments! In this sense, I can also see why Galois groups of polynomials of form $x^6-a$ is not $A_4$.